# React how to pass variable to different function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spfx

I am new to react! But here goes...

I have created a component that consumes a JSON url, then spits out the news feed in a pretty reactive component.

```
  // Grabs the posts from the json url
  public getPosts() {
    axios
      .get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + this.props.jsonUrl)
      .then(response =>
        response.data.map(post => ({
          id: `${post.Id}`,
          name: `${post.Name}`,
          summary: `${post.Summary}`,
          url: `${post.AbsoluteUrl}`,
          imgUrl: `${post.ListingImageUrl}`
        }))
      )
      .then(posts => {
        this.setState({
          posts,
          isLoading: false
        });
      })
    // We can still use the `.catch()` method since axios is promise-based
    .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }
```

I had it set that the user would type in the JSON url in the UI, but now I need to make it work with a drop down selection so I created a switch statement to handle this.

```
  // This will update the json URL for getPosts
  public getCompanyUrl() {
    let url: string = '';
    switch (this.props.listName) {
      case "company1":
        url = "http://example1.co.uk";
        break;
      case 'company2':
        url = "http://example2.co.uk";
        break;
      case 'company3':
         url = "http://example3.co.uk";
        break;
      case 'company4':
        url = "http://example4.co.uk";
        break;
      case 'company5':
        url = "http://example5.co.uk";
        break;
      case 'company6':
        url = "http://example6.co.uk";
        break;
      default:
        url = '';
    }
    console.log(url);
  }
```

How ever I am unsure how to update:

```
.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + this.props.jsonUrl)
```

To take the switch statement url variable instead of `this.props.jsonUrl.`

Any ideas?! :)

Comment: Can't you call the function? `.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + this.getCompanyUrl()) `. Ofcourse then you'd also need to return the `url` from the `getCompanyUrl` function.

Comment: That is a good idea!!! TY @ApplePearPerson post the answer ill accept it :)

Comment: you could as well set the url to state inside  `getCompanyUrl()`  and then just use it inside `getPosts()`

Comment: @harisu Sorry I am new to react, how would I set the state of the url inside getCompanyUrl?

Comment: you create a state variable call url and at the end of the `getCompanyUrl()` where you have `console .log()` you do setState({url, url}) then inside of getPosts() you have `get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" +this.state.url)` but then it will be alot optimal if you do it inside the unchange function of the dropdown that way you will not have to create a getCompanyUrl function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First ensure that `getCompanyUrl` returns the value of the `url`, and that it accepts a `listName` parameter. (Not calling props within this function directly will ensure it's *pure* and more testable).

```
public getCompanyUrl(listName) {
    switch (listName) {
      case "company1":
        return "http://example1.co.uk";
      case 'company2':
        return "http://example2.co.uk";
      case 'company3':
         return "http://example3.co.uk";
      case 'company4':
        return "http://example4.co.uk";
      case 'company5':
        return "http://example5.co.uk";
      case 'company6':
        return "http://example6.co.uk";
      default:
        throw new Error();
    }
  }
```

Then within your `getPosts()` function you can then call this function to return the relevant URL for the company:

```
 axios
      .get(getCompanyUrl(this.props.listName))
    .......
```

---

Alternatively you could simplify this by converting the `getCompanyUrl` into a key/value object and then lookup the value from there:

```
const companies = {
  "company1: "http://example1.co.uk",
  "company2: "http://example2.co.uk",
  "company3: "http://example3.co.uk",
  "company4: "http://example4.co.uk",
  "company5: "http://example5.co.uk",
  "company6: "http://example6.co.uk"
}

  axios
      .get(companies[this.props.listName])
    .......
```